# order by query using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, sql-order-by

I have the following tables:

Products (id,name,description)
Userproducts(id,user_id,product_id)

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT Products.id,Userproducts.user_id 
  FROM Products 
   LEFT JOIN UserProducts 
       ON Products.id = Userproducts.product_id;
```

I'm showing all the products but I want to know how do I make my `ORDER BY` so the top those products will be `Userproducts.user_id =1`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT Products.id,Userproducts.user_id 
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN UserProducts ON Products.id = Userproducts.product_id;
order by Userproducts.user_id
```

Comment: what if user_id is dynamic

Comment: It's Order by automatic in number format.

Comment: @testingone, what do you mean `user_id` is dynamic? Can you [improve your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71013583/edit) by including some sample data and illustrate your expected result?